# Read Contacts Securty Exception Error

Tags: android

I am attempting to read contact details from my app, at the moment just logging to the console but I am encountering security exceptions when testing on the emulator and my own device. I was following this tutorial as a reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4_1UOFNLEY

If anyone can help me on this or point me in the right direction of a better way of accessing the contacts it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    // to gets all contacs
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        // Access specific field of contact
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        //get phone numbers
        Cursor phoneCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{ contactId }, null);

        Log.i("MY INFO", contactId + " = " +contactName);
        //get phone num
        while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
            String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            Log.i("MY INFO", phoneNumber);
        }
        // get email details
        Cursor emailCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String[]{ contactId}, null);

        while(emailCursor.moveToNext()){
            String contactEmail = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

            Log.i("MY INFO", contactEmail);

        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="App">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SignInActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".EditPlayersActivity"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error

```
UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{/u0a275} (pid=7241, uid=10275) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{c71ad8f 7241:com.ciaranbyrne.squad/u0a275} (pid=7241, uid=10275) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1608)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1561)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3598)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5137)
                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2026)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1481)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:488)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:447)
                                                                            at com.ciaranbyrne.squad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
04-24 14:39:39.461 7241-7241/com.ciaranbyrne.squad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.ciaranbyrne.squad, PID: 7241
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ciaranbyrne.squad/com.ciaranbyrne.squad.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{c71ad8f 7241:com.ciaranbyrne.squad/u0a275} (pid=7241, uid=10275) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{c71ad8f 7241:com.ciaranbyrne.squad/u0a275} (pid=7241, uid=10275) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1608)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1561)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3598)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5137)
                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2026)
                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1481)
                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:488)
                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:447)
                                                                         at com.ciaranbyrne.squad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: In the last versions of Android you should get the persmissions at run time
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have run time permission for reading/writing the contact from the device with **API 23** and higher:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

         if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
         }else{
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                       new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                       MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            }
        } else {
           //do your work here
        }
```

---

And read the status:

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Do your work here
                } else {
                  Snackbar.make(mToolbar,getResources().getString(R.string.no_read_contact_permission_message),
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can read more about it in the [Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have device with API 23 Level or High accepted You need to have run time permission for reading/writing the contact :

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                                  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);


And you can call in manifest also:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```